# Eth0 Interface Not Coming Up on Fedora 14

Tags: networking, fedora, linux-networking

I'm trying to upgrade some old Fedora 13 servers to Fedora 14 following [Fedora's docs](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum). The yum commands ran very quickly and seemingly without error. However, when I rebooted after finishing the upgrade to Fedora 14, I found the server was completely offline and I couldn't SSH into it. Logging in manually revealed that the eth0 interface had not been brought up automatically.

My ifcfg-eth0 looks like:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
DHCPCLASS=
DNS1=10.157.10.12
GATEWAY=10.157.10.1
HWADDR=00:0D:12:34:56:78
IPADDR=10.157.10.18
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
OPTIONS=layer2=1
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=5fb16cd0-0bb1-8ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e02
```

Running `sudo ifup eth0` brought up the interface correctly, and the server appears to have no further issues with the upgrade. However, since I've specified `ONBOOT=yes`, why is the interface not being brought up automatically?

Edit:

```
[user@host ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -E "network|Network"
NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run "service network start", does that start the interface also?  If so, run "chkconfig --list" and look for "network" and "NetworkManager".  I think that Fedora 14 added NetworkManager, which is intended more for desktops than servers, and either doesn't process, or processes differently the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts files.  In any case, you want to "chkconfig NetworkManager off", and "chkconfig network on" (assuming "service network start" worked properly).

Comment: Yes, the chkconfig settings were wrong. Also, it seems the upgrade didn't succeed, as the package "alchemist" had some broken dependencies that had created an partial upgrade, and that was somehow interfering with the network service. After I removed alchemist and NetworkManager and did a `yum upgrade`, that fixed everything.